# Custom field population on new Contact

Tags: apex, custom-field, contact

I'm having some issues creating a new contact with apex code. Basically whats happening is that I have a bunch of values getting passed from a lightning component, which should populate in to a new contact. Right now if all I send is the basics like first name, last name, phone, etc., everything works fine. However, when I include some custom fields that we have for the contacts it immediately errors out. The error message isn't any help because its just the standard "internal server error" stuff. Here's the code that I'm using to try to insert the contact:

```
    Contact newContact = new Contact();

    for (string key:contactInfo.keySet()) {
        String value = contactInfo.get(key);
        if (value == 'on') {
            newContact.put(key, true);
        } else if (value == 'off') {
            newContact.put(key, false);
        } else {
            newContact.put(key, contactInfo.get(key));
        }
    }

    try {
        upsert newContact;
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        return errorMessage;
    }
```

the variable **contactInfo** is a map of keys and values that correspond to contact fields. The custom fields that I'm trying to populate are for the most part checkbox data types.

Is it not possible to set these custom fields while you're creating the initial contact? Is there something else with checkbox data types that would be messing this up? Right now I just don't really have any good direction to go in since the error isn't helpful at all. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Question: Do you have necessary access to the fields you trying to populate at Profile level and FLS?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes.

Comment: To debug this, first hardcode the key and values and try to create contact, then you put debug statement and see what values it is being used to create contact. If you are creating contact then use `insert newContact;`

Comment: Can you add your Lightning JS controller to make sure what you are passing from front end....for example, you said it's checkbox fields...what if lightning js is passing 0 or 1 ...but apex is expecting true or false...

Comment: Have you tried Typecasting the values in the controller, before assigning to fields? We have faced this issue earlier, and we solved it by passing the values to Controller by serializing as JSON, and then typecasting the values before assigning.

Comment: Can you check your apex developer console and look for the error. Typically internal server errors show up here and from what I can tell this almost always relate to errors in deserializing the parameters.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212847/lightning-component-action-responds-with-internal-server-error